# What is the difference between these conditional type mapping methods in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Suppose I'd to filter out all the string type fields of a type I could write such code:

```js
// Set the mapped type of value to never
type StringKeysFilterV1<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never };
// Or set the mapped key to never
type StringKeysFilterV2<T> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends string ? K : never]: K };
```

And then I can use them as:

```js
class MyClass {
  public numberField: number = 0;
  public stringField: string = '';
  public booleanField: boolean = false;
}

type Key1 = StringKeysFilterV1<MyClass>[keyof MyClass]; // Result is: "stringField"
type Key2 = keyof StringKeysFilterV2<MyClass>; // Result is also: "stringField"
```

I want to ask what's the difference between these tow methods? Are they identical or not?

And I didn't find any documents to explain how to use the `[K in keyof T as X extends Y ? A : B]` statement inside the key mapper `[]`. Any keywords about this usage?

Comment: No there not identical, they giving you the same result but getting there in different ways.  Your V1 create a type with values as `never` for none string, and then you filters out the keys (keyof), 'never` obviously not returned.  The V2 create a type with only the keys that are string, and then just does a straight keyof on this.   To me V2 seems more logical, as V1 ends up creating a type like -> `{stringField: 'stringField', numberField: unknown}`  seems odd.. :)

Comment: Also to save you having to `keyof` from the caller, I would put that on the type.. eg ->  `type StringKeysFilterV3<T> = keyof { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends string ? K : never]: any };`  Also notice how I've used `any` here instead of of `K`, I think it makes it more obvious what it's doing..  You can then just do -> `type Key3 = StringKeysFilterV3<MyClass>;`

Comment: Would you like to add a more detailed explanation as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you break down each Type into stages you can see what's happening.

So for the V1.

If you just do -> `StringKeysFilterV1<MyClass>` you will see what it creates is ->

```
type Key1 = {
    numberField: never;
    stringField: 'stringField';
    booleanField: never;
}
```

And then what your doing is `keyof` on the above, this works because the values with type `never` will also get filtered out.  To me this seems a little bit of an odd way to do it.

V2 on the other hand produces ->

```
type Key2 = {
    stringField: 'stringField';
}
```

But whats happening here is `{unknown: 'booleanfield', 'stringField':'stringField`,....}`

And then doing `keyof` on the above make a little bit more sense, as an `unknown` key is then filtered instead of the value.

Worth noting that in both case the `value` becomes the `key`.. `stringField: 'stringField'`,  IOW: The last `K` in both could have just been anything, so personally I would replace them with `any`, as its value is not required in the `keyof` part.  IOW: `type StringKeysFilterV2<T> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends string ? K : never]: any };`

Finally instead of doing the `keyof` on the caller, and since the name is called `StringKeysFilter` you can do that also on the type.

`type StringKeysFilterV3<T> = keyof { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends string ? K : never]: any };`

Comment: So V2, transforming the keys in the `[]`statement, is more recommended to do keys filtering right?

Comment: The term for "transformking keys inside `[]`" is [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).

Comment: Thanks for the link. I never get a search result no matter how I combine the keywords `typescript/keyof/as` :p

Answer (score 1):

Your `StringKeysFilterVX` functions create intermediate object types.  It informative to actually create instances of those types to understand what they are:

```
// Set the mapped type of value to never
type StringKeysFilterV1<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never };
// Or set the mapped key to never
type StringKeysFilterV2<T> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends string ? K : never]: K };

class MyClass {
  public numberField: number = 0;
  public stringField: string = '';
  public booleanField: boolean = false;
}

type Key1 = StringKeysFilterV1<MyClass>[keyof MyClass]; // Result is: "stringField"
type Key2 = keyof StringKeysFilterV2<MyClass>; // Result is also: "stringField"

const x0: MyClass  = { 
  stringField: "",
  booleanField: false,
  numberField: 0
};

const x1Fail1: StringKeysFilterV1<MyClass>  = { 
//    ~~~~~~ error
// Type '{ stringField: "stringField"; }' is missing the following 
// properties from type 'StringKeysFilterV1<MyClass>': numberField, booleanField(2739)
  stringField: "stringField",
};

const x1Fudge: StringKeysFilterV1<MyClass>  = { 
  stringField: "stringField",
  booleanField: "booleanField(*&(*&()))" as any as never , // no error!
  numberField: "numberField!%^$^%$^%@$#" as any as never, // no error!
};

// No Error V2
const x2: StringKeysFilterV2<MyClass>  = { 
  stringField: "stringField",
};
```

It is not even possible to instantiate an object of type `StringKeysFilterV1<MyClass>` without fudging.

However you can instantiate an object of type `StringKeysFilterV2<MyClass>` without fudging.

You could also extract the keys without going via an intermediate object as follows:

```
type KeysWithStringValues<T extends object,K = keyof T> = K extends keyof T 
    ?  T[K] extends string ? K : never : never;
type Key3 = KeysWithStringValues<MyClass>; // "stringField"
```

Answer (score -1):

In TypeScript, conditional types allow you to create types that depend on a condition. There are different ways to achieve conditional type mapping, and I'll explain them along with examples:

**1. Simple Conditional Type (Ternary Operator)**

> type MyType = T extends string ? string : number;

In this example, if T extends string, then MyType is string; otherwise, it's number.

**Example:**

> type Result = MyType<"hello">; // Result is "string" type Result2 =
> MyType<42>; // Result2 is "number"

**2. Keyof and Lookup Types**

> type MyType = T extends keyof MyObject ? MyObject[T] : null;

In this example, if T is a key of MyObject, then MyType is the type associated with that key in MyObject; otherwise, it's null.

**Example:**

> ```
> interface MyObject {
>   prop1: string;
>   prop2: number;
> }
>
> type Result1 = MyType<"prop1">; // Result1 is 
> string
> type Result2 = MyType<"prop3">; // Result2 is null
> ```

**4. Extract**

> type MyType = Extract<T, string>; In this example, MyType
> extracts all types from T that are assignable to string.

**Example:**

> type Result = MyType<string | number>; // Result is string

**5. NonNullable**

> type MyType = NonNullable;

NonNullable is a utility type that removes null and undefined from the type T.

**Example:**

> type Result = MyType<string | null | undefined>; // Result is string

**6. Conditional Type Inference**

> type MyType = T extends { a: infer U, b: infer U } ? U : never;

Here, if T extends an object type with properties a and b of the same type, MyType will infer that common type as U.

**Example:**

> type Result = MyType<{ a: string, b: string }>; // Result is string

These are different approaches to conditionally mapping types in TypeScript. The choice of which one to use depends on the specific use case and the kind of conditions you want to apply to your types.

Comment: This does not answer the question - it doesn't even mention key remapping.